# como hacer publicaciones temporales en php y javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, div

quisiera que en cada publicación que haga colocar un  div **< d i v > blabla bla < / d i v >**

y que ese **div "bla bla"** se elimine al pasar ej 24 horas ... pero solo ese **div** no la publicación... como las las historias de fb o instagram ....  si me pueden facilitar el cod y disculpen

para que ese div sea como destacado que se acaba de publicar pero luego sea eliminado por la funcion

Comment: ¿Donde almacenas las publicaciones?

Comment: en la bd tabla noticias ... porq son noticias que publique cada noticia nueva aparesca " nuevo " ... y luego de un tiempo desaparesca la palabra nuevo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, debes añadir a tu base de datos una columna llamada por ejemplo "`publicación`" y le asignas el valor de "`TIMESTAMP`" (Esto hará que nada mas publicar la noticia, se le asigne la fecha actual).

Luego, al recuperar los datos de la noticia para mostrarla en la lista de noticias, debes verificar en cada una si ha pasado X tiempo o no desde su publicación.

Esto lo puedes hacer fácilmente si usas el `WHILE` para mostrar las noticias.

Imaginemos que recuperas los datos en el array `$row`, solo tendrías que hacer esto:

```
$fechaActual = new DateTime();

// while .... {

    $fechaFin = new DateTime($row['publicacion']);
    $fechaFin->modify('+24 hours');

    if ($fechaFin < $fechaActual) {
        echo <div>¡Nuevo!</div>;
    }
// }
```

La variable `$fechaActual` debe ser establecida una sola vez (*no dentro del `while`*).
La variable `$fechaFin` debe estar dentro del `while` y contiene la fecha de creación + 24 horas (*que puedes modificar*).
El `if` comprueba si han pasado las 24 horas, o no. Si aún no han pasado, se hace el echo.

Si no usas `WHILE` para mostrar las noticias, házmelo saber para modificar la respuesta.

Comment: si yo tabajo con el while en lo que pueda pruebo lo comentado mil gracias

Comment: <table>                     <!--tabla dodne se muestra el historial de las notas-->
             </tr>

   <tbody>
      <?php 

      $fechaActual = new DateTime();

      
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($noticias)) {

          $fechaFin = new DateTime($row['tiempo']->modify('+24 hours'));

          ?>

            resto de la tabla donde coloco el  titulo y la foto 

<?php

if ($fechaFin < $fechaActual) {
        echo '<div>¡Nuevo!</div>';
    }
           
         </p>

         <?php } ?>

Comment: como esta escrito en el comentario anterior es como lo ordene en mi tabla  al ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error   

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function modify() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\musica\tablanoticiainicio.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\musica\index.php(151): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\musica\tablanoticiainicio.php on line 29


ojo-- tabla inicio la llamo con un include en index por eos hace referencia ahi

Comment: Lo siento, creo que he cometido un error, prueba con el nuevo código.

Comment: con cual? no lo veo

Comment: @programavzla He modificado el código de mi respuesta. Ahora $fechaFin se establece en 2 líneas. Fíjate bien y cámbialo.

Comment: a ok disculpa  ya reviso

Comment: creo que algo estoy haciendo mal ya que coloque una nueva noticia y no me aparecio el msj de neuvo .. nos podemos comunicar de uan manera mas directa ?